# Looping the list to get the last item present in the list

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, iteration

I want to get a single item in a list at last when the loop completes it's run,

```
word = 'DOOR'
# so the length of word is 4

actual_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Here, i want to run a loop on the `actual_list` with the length of the variable `word`, when the loop completed, it shows the last item present in the list. When i did this problem using pen and paper, i got the item `E` which is not removed by the loop. I also tried this code, but i couldn't got the result successfully,

```
word = 'DOOR'
print(len(word))

actual_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

for w in actual_list[:]:
    if len(actual_list) > 1:
        del actual_list[len(word)-1]
        print(actual_list)
```

Explanation:
The loop remove the 4th item in the list and again the loop will run from the next item after the first item got removed,
Example: after the first loop`['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F']` , after the second loop `['A', 'C', 'E', 'F']` , after the third loop `['C', 'E' ,'F']`, after the fourth loop `['E', 'F']` , after the fifth loop `['E']` likewise, loop continue it's run from the next item where it remove the last item.
When i run the above code, it says, the index gets out of range, i have been stuck here for almost 4 days.
I want the result as,

```
# The last item in the list
['E']
```

Can anyone have solution for this?

Comment: If the word or its length won't change, wouldn't the loop will always remove the list's item at index 3? On the first run it would remove D, during the second one F and probably you will get an Exception during the third loop because no more elements at index 3 will be found. Could you explain explain more about why would the letter 'B' be removed during the second loop?

Comment: Yes, your question is right, the index will exceed out of the range. Here, the process is, after the first item 'D' removed, the loop will continue it's run from the item which is placed after the item it removed previously which is 'E' ('E' is placed after 'D'), so the loop will start from 'E' which comes after 'D', so it will remove the next 4th occurrence of the item from 'E' which is 'B' (4th item from 'E'), likewise it runs until it got the single item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Modulus math can be used to cycle over the `list` while `pop` can be used to remove the element at the target index each pass. Lastly, recursion can be used to repeat those steps until the list is down to one element.

Example:

```
actual_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
word = "DOOR"

def reduce_list(one_list, step, index=0):
    if len(one_list) == 1:
        return one_list[0]
    else:
        pop_index = (index + step) % len(one_list)
        one_list.pop(pop_index)
        print(one_list)
        return reduce_list(one_list, step, pop_index)

print(reduce_list(actual_list, len(word) - 1))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F']
['A', 'C', 'E', 'F']
['C', 'E', 'F']
['E', 'F']
['E']
E
```